# how to overwrite repeated feild values in google buffer protocol

Tags: protocol-buffers

my question is about,how to overwrite the repeated feild in google buffer protocol

Example

```
  message seltMeasureParam
  {
    repeated integer  val = 1;
  }
```

I want to fill val with 255 up to 8000 times using for loop, then i want to fill values at some particular positions within range 4000.
Filling 255 8000 times can be filled easily, i want to know how to fill val at some particular sub-range within 4000 range.

please help in this, thanks in advance

Comment: what library / language / framework are you using? each framework exposes a subtly different API in this scenario.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a few minutes to read the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Then come back and [edit] this question, especially provide a [mcve]. As it is now, your question is likely to be downvoted or closed.

Comment: @akraf FWIW: the question is perfectly clear if you're familiar with protobuf and .proto schemas; there are indeed some clarifications that could be made (hence my comment), but...

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm sorry, apparently I looked over it too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend entirely on the particular language / library that you are using. For example, if I use protobuf-net, the code-gen for `repeated int32 val = 1;` will generate (for that member) either (`syntax="proto2";` or no `syntax` specified):

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, Name = @"val")]
public int[] Vals { get; set; }
```

or (`syntax="proto3";`)

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, Name = @"val", IsPacked = true)]
public int[] Vals { get; set; }
```

So then your code is simply:

```
var arr = new int[8000];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) arr[i] = 255;
obj.Vals = arr;
```

and then later: just set `.Vals[someIndex] = someValue;` with your other values.

How that works in other libraries and languages will vary depending on the API exposed in that framework.